# Routing does not find my ActionResult method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I created a ErrorController with Http400To404 ActionResult for my MVC3 application.

The Route tester matches the specific route. Nonetheless, I get an error that says:

"A public action method 'http400to404' was not found on controller 'Xxxxxx.Yyyyyyyyy.Zzzzzz.Controllers.ErrorController'.

The following is the code for the url:

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
  string url = "~/Error/Http400To404?Exception=System.Exception%3A%20Failed%20to%20authorized% 20the%20request".ToLower();

  filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(url);
}
```

The following is the ErrorController class:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
  [HttpGet]
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Http400To404(Exception e)
  {
   ....
  }

  ...
}
```

I believe it is correctly finding the controller, but for some reason the action result is not picked up. I have tried the following way to make the Url to no avail:

```
string url = urlHelper.RouteUrl("ErrorDefault", 
                            new RouteValueDictionary { { "Exception", (new Exception("Failed to authorized the request.")).ToString() },
                           {"controller","Error"},
                           {"action", "Http400To404"}});
```

I appreacite any help you can provide.
Thank you,
E.

Answer (score 0):

Remove [HttpPost] attribute from the ActionResult. Also by default Actions respond to both GETs and POSTs, so in that case you don't need to specify any attributes.